# Возможности getCount()

Tags: android, java

```
public int getCount() {
     j = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailsj);
}
```

Выдает ощибку с `findViewById`, решил с этим проблему но программа все равно не работает( в чем беда?

Comment: Я полагаю, что getСount() это метод у adapter'a? Он должен возвращать количество элементов, зачем там вызывать findViewById непонятно!

Comment: Какие сделаешь, такие возможности и будут. Что это за getCount? Откуда он?    
Посмотри [вот тут][1]


  [1]: http://goo.gl/jjaaHk

Comment: Спасибо за инфу))

Comment: katso малый опыт, незнал

Answer (score 3):

*How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter.*

[документация по Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html). Как видно он возвращает примитив int. Ну и сам додумай, какие могут быть возможности у примитива ? правильно - только те, которые документированы. Ссылку я дал.

Comment: Спасибо за инфу)